# How can I display without double quote json array data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I replace the double quote "" from my json_encode result.

```
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$json_string = str_replace('"','',$json_string);
echo $json_string;
```

And I fetch data using for loop. code like this:

```
$("#gnumbers").change(function() { 
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var dataString = 'grpid='+ id;    
    $.ajax({                
        url: 'getGroupNumbers.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,  
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {  
            var i, l;
            for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) { 
                $("#num").append(data[i].cnumber + ",");
                //console.log(data[i].cnumber);
            }
        } 
    });
});
```

I checked console.log return nothing but network result something like this: **[{cnumber:8801752992444,group_id:3},{cnumber:8801795978968,8801936761915,group_id:3}]**

Without str_replace i can display data correctly. Even you can see I append multiple rows with comma separated.
My question is how can i display this output result? 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for needing to replace the double quotes? As far as I can tell when you do that you won't be returning  valid JSON response

Comment: I just want to do, pass this values with url parameters and server-side does not belong with that values.  Because with double quote I can not match the syntax.

Comment: The syntax of what?

Answer (score 2):

> I replace the double quote "" from my json_encode result.

This is not a smart thing to do.

You're basically destroying any sense of a useful serialization format.  The quotes are required.  How else would you reliably separate the data from the structure?  How will you differentiate between a comma in a string and a comma as a control character telling you when the next field is to start?  This isn't as simple as doing a string replace.  If you want to invent your own format... I suppose you could do that... but you must take these things into consideration.

You should stick to formats that already exist and are well tested.  JSON is a widely compatible format, which is why it's so heavily used.  If for some reason you need something more compact, consider CBOR or similar.

> How can I display without double quote json array data in jquery

If you wanted to **display** something differently, you wouldn't wreck your data server-side like you're doing now... you'd simply reformat it for display later.

It's acceptable to remove those quotes client-side in your JavaScript.  It's a completely horrible idea to do it server-side where you still need to get useful structured data to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I just want to do, pass this values with url parameters and server-side does not belong with that values.  Because with double quote I can not match the syntax.

Comment: @Roketvai What?  Your comment makes no sense to me... can you add more details and try again?  JSON can contain any valid string, which includes URLs with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

valid JSON format requires keys to be strings in double quotes. When you do str_replace and remove double quotes, you JSON becomes invalid and browser cannot parse it

If you want to convert `cnumber` from string to int then you should do it **before** passing `$data` to `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$json_string = json_encode($data);
echo $json_string
```

And then in the `success` callback,

```
$('#num').append(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.cnumber;
}).join(','));
```

As Brad pointed out, don't replace the double quotes on the server side.